# Bizarre bug with named arguments and implicit struct creation in function call

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-9

Here's a really bizarre bug I recently ran across in CF9. Anyone have a clue why it is occurring and if either I am doing something wrong, or there is a hotfix available. Look at the following code. We take a string, add an A, add a B, and then attempt to add a C... yet the result we get is "ababc". The expected result is "abc". The bug only occurs if you do a named argument AND an implicit struct in argument pass AND a `&=` operator in the function call. If any of those 3 cases is not there, the bug does not occur. Any ideas why?

```
<cffunction name="test">
    <cfargument name="widget">

    <cfset var locals = StructNew()>

    <cfreturn arguments.widget.value>
</cffunction>

<cfset return = "">
<cfset return &= "a">
<cfset return &= "b">
<cfset return &= test(widget = { value = "c" })>
<cfoutput>#return#</cfoutput>
```

Comment: Wow, that is very strange.  File a bug report with Adobe.

Comment: Already did actually http://cfbugs.adobe.com/cfbugreport/flexbugui/cfbugtracker/main.html#bugId=87217 . We'll see if it turns anything up.

Comment: return "abc" in my notebook, XP SP2, ColdFusion Server Developer 9,0,0,251028

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well: you've kinda answered your own question here: it happens because it's a bug. Bugs happen.  It's good you've taken the time to advise Adobe about it.

As for work arounds, these two variations work fine:

```
<cfset return = "">
<cfset return &= "a">
<cfset return &= "b">
<cfset st = { value = "c" }><!--- refactor where the struct is created --->
<cfset return &= test(widget = st)>
<cfoutput>#return#</cfoutput>
```

Or:

```
<cfset return = "">
<cfset return &= "a">
<cfset return &= "b">
<cfset temp = test(widget = { value = "c" })><!--- refactor where the function is called --->
<cfset return &= temp>
<cfoutput>#return#</cfoutput>
```

You're just gonna have to do something like that until Adobe gets around to fixing it :-(

Comment: or simply: `<cfset return = return & test(widget = { value = "c" })>` keep it one line.